# Kademlia get_providers() fails to find nodes that start_providing() in Rust libp2p

Tags: rust, ipfs, dht, kademlia, libp2p

I tried to combine two Rust examples ([ipfs-kad](https://github.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p/blob/master/examples/ipfs-kad/src/main.rs), https://github.com/mxinden/libp2p-lookup and [chat-example](https://github.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p/tree/master/examples/chat-example)) that use Kademlia to locate their peers to create a shared message channel.

**However when I run 2 nodes that try to locate each other, they don't find each other:**

```
Enter messages via STDIN and they will be sent to connected peers using Gossipsub
Other Kademlia event: RoutingUpdated { peer: PeerId("QmNnooDu7bfjPFoTZYxMNLWUQJyrVwtbZg5gBMjTezGAJN"), is_new_peer: true, addresses: ["/dnsaddr/bootstrap.libp2p.io"], bucket_range: (Distance(57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968), Distance(115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935)), old_peer: None }
Other Kademlia event: RoutingUpdated { peer: PeerId("QmQCU2EcMqAqQPR2i9bChDtGNJchTbq5TbXJJ16u19uLTa"), is_new_peer: true, addresses: ["/dnsaddr/bootstrap.libp2p.io"], bucket_range: (Distance(14474011154664524427946373126085988481658748083205070504932198000989141204992), Distance(28948022309329048855892746252171976963317496166410141009864396001978282409983)), old_peer: None }
Other Kademlia event: RoutingUpdated { peer: PeerId("QmbLHAnMoJPWSCR5Zhtx6BHJX9KiKNN6tpvbUcqanj75Nb"), is_new_peer: true, addresses: ["/dnsaddr/bootstrap.libp2p.io"], bucket_range: (Distance(57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968), Distance(115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935)), old_peer: None }
Other Kademlia event: RoutingUpdated { peer: PeerId("QmcZf59bWwK5XFi76CZX8cbJ4BhTzzA3gU1ZjYZcYW3dwt"), is_new_peer: true, addresses: ["/dnsaddr/bootstrap.libp2p.io"], bucket_range: (Distance(14474011154664524427946373126085988481658748083205070504932198000989141204992), Distance(28948022309329048855892746252171976963317496166410141009864396001978282409983)), old_peer: None }
Finished getting providers, waiting for other peers to connect; closest peers: []
Published this node as a provider for key
Local node is listening on /ip4/...
Local node is listening on /ip6/...
...
test message
Publish error: InsufficientPeers
```

It seems that it fails because it's unable to find closest peers.

My code:

```rust
use async_std::io;
use futures::{prelude::*, select};
use libp2p::{
    core::muxing::StreamMuxerBox,
    gossipsub, identity,
    kad::{
        record::store::MemoryStore, GetProvidersOk, Kademlia, KademliaConfig, KademliaEvent,
        QueryResult, RecordKey,
    },
    swarm::NetworkBehaviour,
    swarm::{SwarmBuilder, SwarmEvent},
    PeerId, Swarm, Transport,
};
use libp2p_quic as quic;
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;
use std::error::Error;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
use std::time::Duration;

// We create a custom network behaviour that combines Gossipsub and Kademlia.
#[derive(NetworkBehaviour)]
struct MyBehaviour {
    gossipsub: gossipsub::Behaviour,
    kademlia: Kademlia<MemoryStore>,
}

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    env_logger::init();

    // Create a random PeerId
    let local_peer = identity::Keypair::generate_ed25519();
    let local_peer_id = PeerId::from(local_peer.public());
    println!("Local peer id: {local_peer_id}");

    let shared_dht_key =
        RecordKey::new(&"12D3KooWD3mFq2ijumTBcnuG5jQh3qC7ChjLNwf5WaPjh3aAWJr9".as_bytes());

    let quic_transport = quic::async_std::Transport::new(quic::Config::new(&local_peer));
    let transport = quic_transport
        .map(|output, _| match output {
            (peer_id, muxer) => (peer_id, StreamMuxerBox::new(muxer)),
        })
        .boxed();

    // To content-address message, we can take the hash of message and use it as an ID.
    let message_id_fn = |message: &gossipsub::Message| {
        let mut s = DefaultHasher::new();
        message.data.hash(&mut s);
        gossipsub::MessageId::from(s.finish().to_string())
    };

    // Set a custom gossipsub configuration
    let gossipsub_config = gossipsub::ConfigBuilder::default()
        .heartbeat_interval(Duration::from_secs(10)) // This is set to aid debugging by not cluttering the log space
        .validation_mode(gossipsub::ValidationMode::Strict) // This sets the kind of message validation. The default is Strict (enforce message signing)
        .message_id_fn(message_id_fn) // content-address messages. No two messages of the same content will be propagated.
        .build()
        .expect("Valid config");

    // build a gossipsub network behaviour
    let mut gossipsub = gossipsub::Behaviour::new(
        gossipsub::MessageAuthenticity::Signed(local_peer),
        gossipsub_config,
    )
    .expect("Correct configuration");
    // Create a Gossipsub topic
    let topic = gossipsub::IdentTopic::new("test-net");
    // subscribes to our topic
    gossipsub.subscribe(&topic)?;

    // Create a Kademlia behaviour.
    let mut kademlia = Kademlia::with_config(
        local_peer_id,
        MemoryStore::new(local_peer_id),
        KademliaConfig::default(),
    );
    for peer in &BOOTNODES {
        kademlia.add_address(&peer.parse()?, "/dnsaddr/bootstrap.libp2p.io".parse()?);
    }

    // Create a Swarm to manage peers and events
    let mut swarm = {
        let behaviour = MyBehaviour {
            gossipsub,
            kademlia,
        };
        SwarmBuilder::with_async_std_executor(transport, behaviour, local_peer_id).build()
    };

    // Read full lines from stdin
    let mut stdin = io::BufReader::new(io::stdin()).lines().fuse();

    // Listen on all interfaces and whatever port the OS assigns
    swarm.listen_on("/ip4/0.0.0.0/udp/0/quic-v1".parse()?)?;
    swarm.listen_on("/ip6/::0/udp/0/quic-v1".parse()?)?;

    println!("Enter messages via STDIN and they will be sent to connected peers using Gossipsub");

    // Kick it off
    let kademlia = &mut swarm.behaviour_mut().kademlia;
    kademlia.start_providing(shared_dht_key.clone())?;
    kademlia.get_providers(shared_dht_key.clone());
    loop {
        select! {
            line = stdin.select_next_some() => {
                if let Err(e) = swarm
                    .behaviour_mut().gossipsub
                        .publish(topic.clone(), line.expect("Stdin not to close").as_bytes()) {
                            println!("Publish error: {e:?}");
                            // Let's try to fetch providers again.
                            swarm.behaviour_mut().kademlia.get_providers(shared_dht_key.clone());
                }
            },
            event = swarm.select_next_some() => match event {
                SwarmEvent::Behaviour(MyBehaviourEvent::Kademlia(kademlia_event)) =>
                    match kademlia_event {
                        KademliaEvent::OutboundQueryProgressed {
                            result: QueryResult::Bootstrap(result),
                            ..
                        } => {
                            result?;
                            panic!("Unexpected bootstrap");
                        }
                        KademliaEvent::OutboundQueryProgressed {
                            result: QueryResult::GetProviders(Ok(GetProvidersOk::FoundProviders{ providers, .. })),
                            ..
                        } => {
                            for peer_id in providers {
                                if peer_id != local_peer_id && !Swarm::is_connected(&swarm, &peer_id) {
                                    println!("Kademlia discovered a new peer: {peer_id}");
                                    // TODO: Kademlia might not be caching the address of the peer.
                                    Swarm::dial(&mut swarm, peer_id)?;
                                    swarm.behaviour_mut().gossipsub.add_explicit_peer(&peer_id);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        KademliaEvent::OutboundQueryProgressed {
                            result: QueryResult::GetProviders(Ok(GetProvidersOk::FinishedWithNoAdditionalRecord{ closest_peers })),
                            ..
                        } => {
                            println!("Finished getting providers, waiting for other peers to connect; closest peers: {closest_peers:?}");
                        },
                        KademliaEvent::OutboundQueryProgressed {
                            result: QueryResult::StartProviding(add_provider),
                            ..
                        } => {
                            add_provider?;
                            println!("Published this node as a provider for key");
                        },
                            ev => {
                                println!("Other Kademlia event: {ev:?}");
                            },
                    },
                    SwarmEvent::Behaviour(MyBehaviourEvent::Gossipsub(gossipsub::Event::Message {
                        propagation_source: peer_id,
                        message_id: id,
                        message,
                    })) => println!("Got message: '{}' with id: {id} from peer: {peer_id}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&message.data)),
                    SwarmEvent::NewListenAddr { address, .. } => {
                        println!("Local node is listening on {address}");
                    }
                _ => {}
            }
        }
    }
}

const BOOTNODES: [&str; 4] = [
    "QmNnooDu7bfjPFoTZYxMNLWUQJyrVwtbZg5gBMjTezGAJN",
    "QmQCU2EcMqAqQPR2i9bChDtGNJchTbq5TbXJJ16u19uLTa",
    "QmbLHAnMoJPWSCR5Zhtx6BHJX9KiKNN6tpvbUcqanj75Nb",
    "QmcZf59bWwK5XFi76CZX8cbJ4BhTzzA3gU1ZjYZcYW3dwt",
];
```

---

([Double-posted](https://discuss.libp2p.io/t/kademlia-get-providers-fails-to-find-nodes-that-start-providing-in-rust-libp2p/2026) on the libp2p forum.)